# Query MySQL To Show Counting from the table relation

Tags: php, mysql, regex

i have 3 tables. 2 reference table and one table transactions.

1. Table puskesmas

mysql> select id,nama from puskesmas;

```
+----+----------------------+
| id | nama                 |
+----+----------------------+
|  1 | BAMBANGLIPURO        |
|  2 | BANGUNTAPAN          |
|  3 | BANTUL               |
|  4 | DLINGO               |
|  5 | IMOGIRI              |
|  6 | JETIS                |
|  7 | KASIHAN              |
|  8 | KRETEK               |
|  9 | PAJANGAN             |
| 10 | PANDAK               |
+----+----------------------+
```

2. Table poli

mysql> select * from poli;

```
+----+---------------+
| id | nama          |
+----+---------------+
|  1 | BP            |
|  2 | KIA           |
|  3 | GIGI          |
|  4 | JIWA          |
+----+---------------+
```

3. Table loket

mysql> select pasien_id,poli_id,puskesmas_id from loket limit 10;

```
+-----------+---------+--------------+
| pasien_id | poli_id | puskesmas_id |
+-----------+---------+--------------+
|         1 |       1 |            1 |
|         5 |       2 |            2 |
|         1 |       1 |            3 |
|         9 |       3 |            4 |
|         1 |       3 |            5 |
|         5 |       2 |            1 |
|         1 |       1 |            3 |
|         8 |       1 |            2 |
|        10 |       3 |            6 |
|         5 |       2 |            5 |
+-----------+---------+--------------+
```

I want to show the total number (count) of visits to puskesmas table. then made field all_total
fter that I want to take patient visits where poli_id = 1 and used as a column bp. for other poly are the same as the

```
+----+----------------------+--------------+------+------+------+------+
| id | nama                 | All Total    |  BP  |  KIA | GIGI | JIWA |
+----+----------------------+--------------+------+------+------+------+
|  1 | BAMBANGLIPURO        |     30       |  10  |  3   |  15  |  2   |
|  2 | BANGUNTAPAN          |     35       |  20  |  4   |  11  |  0   |
|  3 | BANTUL               |     15       |  10  |  0   |  5   |  0   |
|  4 | DLINGO               |     12       |  10  |  1   |  1   |  0   |
|  5 | IMOGIRI              |     10       |  5   |  2   |  1   |  2   |
|  6 | JETIS                |     25       |  13  |  3   |  7   |  2   |
|  7 | KASIHAN              |     20       |  10  |  10  |  0   |  0   |
|  8 | KRETEK               |     23       |  20  |  1   |  1   |  1   |
|  9 | PAJANGAN             |     10       |  5   |  1   |  3   |  1   |
| 10 | PANDAK               |     0        |  0   |  0   |  0   |  0   |
+----+----------------------+--------------+------+------+------+------+
```

I've tried to make a query to display like this but it always fails to hold. Can anyone help to make such queries desired results

i have tried query like this :
select puskesmas_id,
  sum(case when poli_id=1 then 1 else 0 end) bp,
  sum(case when poli_id=5 then 0 else 1 end) gigi,
  count(id) total
from loket
group by puskesmas_id

and result like this :

```
+--------------+------+------+-------+
| puskesmas_id | bp   | gigi | total |
+--------------+------+------+-------+
|            1 |   97 |  126 |   143 |
|            6 |   74 |  185 |   210 |
|            8 |  131 |  179 |   190 |
|            7 |   90 |   92 |    98 |
|            2 |   33 |   39 |    54 |
|            4 |  158 |  248 |   263 |
|            3 |   66 |   68 |    72 |
+--------------+------+------+-------+
```

but puskesmas_id the value 0 does not perform data when querying

Comment: You have a lot of formatting problems there. Maybe upload an image, or put in code tags and try to line it up with tabs.

Comment: @Evan Carslake : already revision. thx for Drew Pierce

Comment: Yes, right. but I do not want to translate into health clinic for table names used herein Puskesmas worried confusing.

Comment: i was just trying to grasp the concept to perform a join as at first it was chicken soup didnt know what was what now i understand

Comment: The 4 rows of `poli` are guaranteed to be there. ... no more no less